# How to filter out first line from an variable in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I imported a `cvs` file to an variable like below:

```
basketball_players = load '/usr/data/basketball_players.csv' using PigStorage(',');
```

below is the output of the first 3 lines:

```
tmp = limit basketball_players 3;
dump tmp

("playerID","year","stint","tmID","lgID","GP","GS","minutes","points","oRebounds","dRebounds","rebounds","assists","steals","blocks","turnovers","PF","fgAttempted","fgMade","ftAttempted","ftMade","threeAttempted","threeMade","PostGP","PostGS","PostMinutes","PostPoints","PostoRebounds","PostdRebounds","PostRebounds","PostAssists","PostSteals","PostBlocks","PostTurnovers","PostPF","PostfgAttempted","PostfgMade","PostftAttempted","PostftMade","PostthreeAttempted","PostthreeMade","note")
("abramjo01","1946","1","PIT","NBA","47","0","0","527","0","0","0","35","0","0","0","161","834","202","178","123","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",)
("aubucch01","1946","1","DTF","NBA","30","0","0","65","0","0","0","20","0","0","0","46","91","23","35","19","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",)
```

you can see that the first line is the header of the table. I use below command to filter out the first line but it doesn't work.

```
grunt> players_raw = filter basketball_players by $1 > 0;
2017-05-06 11:03:36,389 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_INT 6 time(s).
```

when I dump the value of `players_raw` it returns empty. How can I filter the first row out from an variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RANK](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#rank) to generate a new column that will add row numbers to the dataset.Use that column to filter the first row.

```
basketball_players = load '/usr/data/basketball_players.csv' using PigStorage(',');
ranked = rank basketball_players;
basketball_players_without_header = Filter ranked by (rank_basketball_players > 1);
DUMP basketball_players_without_header;
```

Another way to do this

```
basketball_players = load '/usr/data/basketball_players.csv' using PigStorage(',');
basketball_players_without_header = Filter basketball_players by ($0 matches '.*playerID.*');
DUMP basketball_players_without_header;
```